FastReport with image - Export to HTML wth images from external URL
When sending a report via email, we normally export to PDF and attach that file to the email.
We now need to show the report in the body of the email.   No PDF attachment.
To do this, we export the report to HTML and assign the resultant HTML to the body of the email.
This works well except for images.  Like HTML emails we all get, we want to images to be loaded from a web server.   We know the image URL at design time.
The issue is that FastReports gets the image from the server and writes it to a folder.  It is this local image that is referenced in the exported HTML like so:
<img width=606 height=392 src="Test_HTML_Image_files/image002.png"
What we want is for the exported HTML to reference the image via the URL like so:
<img width=606 height=392 src="https://xxxx.com.au/uploads/yyy/mm/zzz.jpg">
I have tried both frxPictureView and frxHTMLView components without success.
How can I "pass through" an image URL to the exported report HTML?
Many thanks!
